# Is it possible (or ok) to have a std::list of std::list's?

Tags: c++

I have a std::list of Points (that simply store an x, y).  Each one of these points represents a polygon, which I later draw.

```
class Point {
public:
    int x, y;
    Point(int x1, int y1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
};

std::list <Point> currentPolygon;
```

I would like to have a list of these polygons (lists themselves).

Is this possible?  How do I have a std::list of a list of Points (so I can store more than one polygon).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use this:

```
std::list< std::list<Point> > polygons;
```

To make things easier, use typedefs.

```
class Point {
public:
    int x, y;
    Point(int x1, int y1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
};
typedef std::list<Point> PolygonType;
typedef std::list<PolygonType> PolygonsType;
```

Comment: don't forget the space between > and > in std::list<std::list<Point> >, or the parser would think you want to do a right shift and complain.

Answer (score 10):

It sure is.  But what you probably want - for expandability purposes later - create a second class - "polygon", that holds a list of points.  Then use a list of polygons.

EDIT: I'm no C++ programmer, so I'm sure an implementation like [j_random_hacker's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544206/is-it-possible-or-ok-to-have-a-stdlist-of-stdlists/544685#544685) response is better if you're needing this for a real project.  I merely wanted to give a quickie code example of this design.

```
class Point {
public:
    int x, y;
    Point(int x1, int y1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
};

class Polygon {
public:
    std::list <Point> currentPolygon;
    Polygon(std::list <Point> p1)
    {
        currentPolygon = p1
    }
};
```

Comment: std:list overloads the assignment operator so yes that will work.

Comment: Sweet... I've been living too long in the .net arraylist and hashtable world.

Comment: Basically OK but I'm -1ing you since you're employing several bad habits: (1) You should declare your Polygon ctor "explicit" to avoid implicit conversions from list<Point>; (2) pass p1 by const ref to the ctor; (3) Point and Polygon ctors should both initialise members using an initialiser list.

Comment: Sounds fair enough.  Feel free to edit if the link isn't sufficient enough.  I see you have the rep ;-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thanks for that.  I prefer not to edit others' answers to change the meaning of what they wrote, I just fix typos etc.  (And insert the odd "j_random_hacker RULZ!!!11!1" :-P)

Answer (score 4):

Here is Jeffrey's code again, tidied up slightly to fix what I was whingeing about in the comments :)

```
class Point {
public:
    int x, y;
    Point(int x1, int y1) : x(x1), y(y1)
    {
    }
};

class Polygon {
public:
    std::list <Point> currentPolygon;    // Consider making this private.
    explicit Polygon(std::list <Point> const& p1) : currentPolygon(p1)
    {
    }
};
```

**[EDIT: Thanks to Matt Davis for pointing out that the user-defined copy constructor I provided was unnecessary, which simplifies things.]**

Comment: Unless I'm not remembering the Scott Meyers "Effective C++" correctly, the compiler provides the copy constructor as well.

Comment: @Matt Davis: You're right, I've now fixed this.  (For some reason I thought maybe compiler auto-generation of copy ctors might be turned off by providing any 1-parameter ctor of your own, but of course that parameter has to be a (possibly const and/or volatile) reference to the class's own type.)